# Android EditText max text length limited

Tags: android, user-interface

I have written a simple text editor, using EditText component in Android.
It is working properly on many devices, but on an LG G Pad, text length is limited to **10500** characters ( unicode).
I have set **android:maxLength="9999999"** but it has no effect!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JVAm8vBaIQg see this link hope would be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Blog should be useful to solve this issue. Basically, use filter.

http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But why it's not same on different devices?

Comment: I really don't know to be honest.